# Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

My AdminMiddleware code is::

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Sentinel;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Sentinel::check()&&Sentinel::getUser()->roles()->first()->slug =='admin')
            return $next($request);
        else
            return redirect('/accessories');    
    }
}
```

and when I wanna go to ::

```
Route::get('/earnings', 'AdminController@earnings')->middleware('admin');
```

it shows an error like this:

> Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object

Comment: `print_r(Sentinel::getUser()->roles());` and see if the logged in user has any roles.

Comment: Check hat , you are getting roles and data in first method ?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because *`Sentinel::getUser()->roles()`* is not an object which means: **User does not have any role**

Add another check

```
if(Sentinel::check() && isset(Sentinel::getUser()->roles) && Sentinel::getUser()->roles()->first()->slug =='admin'){
//Other code
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much but I already found the problem and fix it by myself